# Is there a more rigorous method of notating arithmetic?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Is there a method of notating arithmetic that presents the transformations more explicitly than the standard method?

For example.

Someone using the standard method might present their solution for x in 3*(4/2)+x=7 thus:

3*(4/2)+x=7

3*2+x=7

6+x=7

x=7-6

x=1

In this simple example the transformations would probably seem obvious to almost everyone. However I can imagine some cases where the transformations wouldn't seem so obvious.

Natural deduction and Finch notation present the transformations to the right of the expression. Is there a comparable way of presenting arithmetic?

Comment: If there is, I hope no one in a Faculty of Education ever finds out.

Comment: you could try using Math Jax....

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm imagining it as something useful for checking your work (like double-entry accounting) to catch dropped signs, and for helping learners see that just a few laws enable all the transformations they use. It probably wouldn't benefit experienced mathematicians.

Comment: Good question, and please ignore Andre's sad remark.

Answer (score 1):

Well performing the operations first should be very obvious, I would probably present that in the following way:

$$
3 \cdot 2 + x = 7 \\
6 + x = 7 \\
6 + x + (-6) = 7 +(-6) \\
6 + (-6) + x = 1 \\
0 + x = 1
x = 1
$$

Explaing at each step like (adding -6 to both sides), or (computing the sum of 7 + (-6))